# How to Detect Specific Regular Expression Pattern in Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, regex

From text editor [summernote](https://summernote.org/), I tried to detect if I type a specific pattern, for this case a string start with `{{`, `{%` and close with `}}`, `%}` respectively, and if it is matched I set it to `localStorage`.

So I tried my code with no avail like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jinja2Code').summernote({
    /* update key word*/
    callbacks: {
      onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
        // remove html tag
        contents = contents.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
        var regex1 = /^\{\{.*\}\}$/g; //  match for {# {{any character}} #}
        var regex2 = /^\{\%.*\%\}$/g; //  match for {% set variable_name = value %} #}
        var key = '';
        // update to local storage
        if (regex1.test(contents)) {
          console.log('regex1 matched');
          key = contents.replace(/\[\{\{\]+\[\}\}\]/g, ""); // {# remove {{ and }} #}
          console.log('key: ' + key);
          localStorage.setItem(key, contents);
        }
        if (regex2.test(contents)) {
          console.log('regex2 matched');
          key = contents.replace(/\{\%\%\}/g, "") // {# remove {%, set, =, and %} #}
          localStorage.setItem(key, contents);
        }
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!-- Include BS and FA -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
  
  <textarea name="" class="jinja2Code" cols="10" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

I would like it to be:

**Regex1**:

Input "{{ hello }}", result : `key` as hello, and `contents` as {{hello}}

**Regex2**:

Input "{% set variableName = 'hello' %}", result: `key` as `variablename` and `contents` as hello.

Then from above, I would save it to `localStorage` as `localStorage.setItem(key, contents);`.

However, `regex1` matched even I typed only `{{}}`, and matched even I typed `{%%}`, and `key` does not replace character as expected.

What is wrong missing in my script, how I can correct it achieve above result?

I have google around but not meet my case, and I'm have very knowledge about regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: What does:
Regex1: input "{{ hello }}", result : hello:{{hello}}
mean? Do you want the spaces to be trimmed?

Comment: @D.Braun, sorry not being clear, it meant when type in {{hello}} I would like to set `key` as `hello` and contents as `{{hello}}, so that I saved it to `localStorage` as `localStorage.setItem(key, contents);`. I will edit my question. Thanks

Comment: Culd there be spaces between "{{" and "hello" ?

Comment: @D.Braun, the same for `regex2`, if type in `{% set varName = value %}, I would like to set `key` as `varName`, and `contents` as `value` so that I saved it to `localStorage` as `localStorage.setItem(key, contents);` :)

Comment: @D.Braun yes, it optionally have whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.* means any character zero or more times
=> /^{{.*}}$/ matches {{}}

.+ means any character one or more times

.+? means nay character one or more times and not greedy

about greedy and lazy you can read something here:
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

So for regex1 ({{ text }}) I would use:

```
var regex1 = /^\{\{\s*?.+?\s*?\}\}$/g;
```

For regex2 ({% key set = value %}):

```
/^\{\%\s*?set?s*?(\w+?)\s*?=\s*?(\w+?)\%\}$/g
```

If you need {% key set = 'value' %}

```
/^\{\%\s*?set?s*?(\w+?)\s*?=\s*?'(\w+?)'\%\}$/g
```

That means:

Starts with {%: ^{\%

Then there could ba a space: \s*?

The the word set: set

Then there could ba a space: \s*?

The variable name made from letters, numbers and _ in a group: (\w+?)

Then there could ba a space: \s*?

Now a =: =

Then there could ba a space: \s*?

The variable value made from letters, numbers and _ in a group: (\w+?)

Ends with %}: \%}$

The groups () in the regex you can use to make the replacements. The grous are called $1 und $2 and so on.

Splitting the {% set key = value %} in key and value and saving it in the local storage:

```
const result = contents.match(/^\{\%\s*?set?s*?(\w+?)\s*?=\s*?(\w+?)\%\}$/g);
if (result) {
    let key;
    let value;
    if (result.length > 1)
      key = result[1] ;
    }
    if (result.length > 2)
      value = result[2] ;
    }
    if (key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
}
```

Getting the key from the {{ text }} and saving it in the local storage:

```
const result2 = contents.match(/^\{\{\s*?(\w+?)\s*?\}\}$/g);
if (result2) {
    let key;
    if (result2.length > 1)
      key = result2[1] ;
    }
    if (key) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, key);
    }
}
```

I hope it works, unfortunately I have no time to test it.